# Has anyone tried to deploy artifacts to Rational Asset Manager

Tags: rtc, jazz, ibm-jazz

I am experimenting the use of Rational Asset Manager to store our binaries and/or build artifacts. I am running a mvn deploy command to deploy my build artifacts to RAM. Although it recognizes the connection its throwing me a Http status code: 500 error.

I have also checked RAM logs for more information but i don't see any specific exception. All the examples or documents out on internet says we have to configure RTC build engine to run the builds.

I just want to know if anyone have tried publishing to RAM from command line using Mvn deploy ( without using RTC client ) ? is this do-able?

If you have successfully published artifacts to RAM using maven, can you please elaborate on how you did it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to deploy the artifact using mvn deploy after changing the following things in RAM

- Pointed to a JRE version in RAM ( originally was pointing to JDK
  version) and
- Changed permissions for my role for  saving my artifacts
  in RAM ("save Work Item") [Reference](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/108980/save-work-item-operation-cannot-be-completed)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possible, if you follow the steps described in:

- "[Creating and using Maven assets](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ramhelp/v7r5m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ram.web.doc/topics/t_create_use_maven.html)", and
- "[Deploying from Maven to assets](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ramhelp/v7r5m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ram.web.doc/topics/t_deploy_from_maven.html)":

> Before you can use Maven assets, a repository administrator must enable the Maven model library. For more information, see **[Enabling the Maven library](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ramhelp/v7r5m1/topic/com.ibm.ram.web.doc/topics/t_enable_maven_library.html)**.
>
> The `mvn` client can integrate with Rational Asset Manager, using Rational Asset Manager as a Maven repository.
>
> Before you deploy from Maven to Rational Asset Manager, you must add a repository entry to the `pom.xml` file on the computer where you plan to run the `mvn` client. See **[Creating and using Maven assets](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ramhelp/v7r5m1/topic/com.ibm.ram.web.doc/topics/t_create_use_maven.html#t_create_use_maven__m2dir)** for more information.